# appmenu in 14.04 for gtk2 apps?

Tags: appmenu

Appmenu in 14.04 doesn't seem to be working for GTK2 apps like Pidgin or Meld 1.3, whereas it worked fine in 13.10.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the GTK package for the menus?
try this `sudo apt-get install unity-gtk2-module`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be missing the package `unity-gtk2-module`

```
sudo apt-get install unity-gtk2-module
```

Or it may be installed wrong

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-gtk2-module
```

Also make sure you restart or logout in order to make sure everything works right you may not have to do this, you may simply need to restart the program.

[image]

Comment: That is actually a screenshot of Meld 3 which uses GTK3, but thanks, your advice worked!